# VHDL : Aliasing part of an Array

Tags: arrays, vhdl, alias

I am using Synplify Pro Logic Synthesis toolset for Actel FPGAs.
I have a `std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)` array type `hexArray` declared like this

```
    type hexArray is array(0 to 10) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal sRes : hexArray;
```

I like to create an `alias` for the part of 'sResponse' sliced from different positions as shown below,

```
alias sData  : std_logic_vector(22 downto 0) is (sRes(2)(6 downto 0) & sRes(1) & sRes(0));
```

The above snippet tries to form a 23 bit `alias` sData by combining different parts of the signal `sRes`. But, it fails to run. Is it not possible to alias part of an array?

Comment: The snippet produces an error during analysis (compilation) not when run. `(sRes(2)(6 downto 0) & sRes(1) & sRes(0))` is an expression. IEEE Std 1076-2008, 9. Expressions, 9.1 General "An expression is a formula that defines the computation of a value." 6.6 Alias declarations, 6.6.1 General para 1 "An alias declaration declares an alternate name for an existing named entity. "Is it not possible to alias part of an array?* Yes it is not possible. (Don't ask yes or no questions.)

Comment: Agreed. Basically, I want to reuse the refered portion of the array with a better name.

Comment: To what have you agreed?  What you want is apparent. It isn't clear what 'better' means. Your question doesn't ask for an alternative which would require a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem (with it's error message) and solution(s) for future readers using Q & As as search resources. So far you've just expressed an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) with an unclear problem. Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVDQu.jpg) 'better'?

Comment: An alias must be declared to a single object, or a slice of an array object. You cannot combine multiple objects into an alias. You need another signal or variable to do what you want. eg. `signal sData  : std_logic_vector(22 downto 0);  sData <= (sRes(2)(6 downto 0) & sRes(1) & sRes(0));`

Comment: A little more of your code would be helpful.